# Why is my application creating huge number of connections are putting them in Finaliser?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, database-connection, hikaricp

We are facing an issue with the application reaching the maximum number of connections. This is a Java+SpringBoot setup with DB Multitenancy. So, multiple thread pools are an expectation as long as there is only one pool per database. We are seeing issues saying, "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection." We bumped up our pool size, and the issue is gone for now, but the application should not require these many connections, as most connections are sitting idle on the Postgres DB.

When we look at the heap dump, we see 32 connection pools, 4 are duplicates; giving us to assume that there are multi-threading issues in the code initializing the connection pools. Is this understanding correct?

When we look at the PGConnection object, there are 666 of those, and a whole lot are showing up as "referent in Finalizer", which indicates they are marked for garbage collection but not yet removed. Is this understanding correct?

What should we check next? What could be the potential causes for something like this?

[image]

Comment: Check your code, next to that you probably have a connection leak in your code due to messing around with connections yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing